# What is the formal definition for $\sim$ in the context of statistics?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

If $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$, we say that $X$ follows a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma$. How is the operator $\sim$ formally defined?

Comment: It merely reads "is distributed."  Are you then asking for a formal definition of a distribution?

Answer (score 5):

[Quoth the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Kolmogorov_definition):

In the measure-theoretic formalization of probability theory, a random variable  is defined as a measurable function $X$ from a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \operatorname{P})$ to measurable space $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{A})$. A probability distribution of $X$ is the pushforward measure $X.P$  of $X$ , which is a probability measure on $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{A})$ satisfying $X.P$ = $PX^{-1}$

So $\sim$ means that the right hand side is the probability distribution of the random variable on the left hand side.

Comment: Sometimes one also writes $X \sim Y$ to say that $X$ and $Y$ have the same law.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Unless $\sim$ was given an explicit definition that way, I'd tend to regard that as an informally clear enough but formally loose notation for $X\sim F_Y$

Comment: @Glen_b Say $X \sim Y$ when $X$ and $Y$ have the same law. This is an equivalence relation. The law of $X$ can be viewed as the representative of the class of $X$, therefore this is consistent with $X \sim dF_X$.

Comment: If we take $~$ to indicate an equivalence relation (and I'd call that "an explicit definition that way" under my previous comment), then yes, that's precise.